# Split Single Image in Four Pices

Tags: android, image, split

I want to Split Single Image in Four Pieces  and Display it Like Single Image. How can achieve it. I split image through bitmap but it is not fixing in like one single image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to achieve the same thing. I think this can be done by Android APIs but I would need make more research before answering on that. All I know there is a Java way to that. It might help http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-split-image-into-chunks-java.html

Comment: I have achieved it by splitting bitmap by half of width and half of hight. Than you can create four bitmap.